# How to make the calculation of the median faster in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, numpy, median

I would like to calculate the median line by line in a dataframe of more than 500,000 rows. For the moment I'm using `np.median` because numpy is optimized to run on a single core.  It's still very slow and I'd like to find a way to parallel the calculation

Specifically, I have `N` tables of size `13 x 500,000` and for each table I want to add the columns Q1, Q3 and median so that for each row the median column contains the median of the row. So I have to calculate `N * 500,000` median values.

I tried with `numexpr` but it doesn't seem possible.

**EDIT :**
In fact I also need Q1 and Q3 so I can't use the statistics module which doesn't allow to calculate quartiles. Here is how I calculate the median for the moment

```
    q = np.transpose(np.percentile(data[row_array], [25,50,75], axis = 1))
    data['Q1_' + family] = q[:,0]
    data['MEDIAN_' + family] = q[:,1]
    data['Q3_' + family] = q[:,2]
```

**EDIT 2** I solved my problem by using the median of median algorithm as proposed below

Comment: Have you tried this??

`import statistics
statistics.median(items)`

Comment: Look at the edit part of the question, thank you for your answer

Comment: Q1 is the median of lowest value and median of dataset, so you can calculate in that way .

Comment: Okay I didn't know it, but I think it's still more interesting to calculate the 3 all at once like this from a computation time point of view. 

In fact to speed up the calculation I was thinking of parallelizing the operations but I don't know how to do it

Comment: Would it always have 3 columns?

Comment: exactly there will never be more than 3 columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a (close) approximation of the median is OK for your purposes, you should consider computing a *median of medians*, which is a divide and conquer strategy that can be executed in parallel. In principle, *MoM* has `O(n)` complexity for serial execution, approaching `O(1)` for parallel execution on massively parallel systems.

See [this Wiki entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians) for a description and pseudo-code. See also [this question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10806303/python-implementation-of-median-of-medians-algorithm) and discussion of the code, and [this ArXiv paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1104.2732v1) for a GPU implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Courtesy of @dahhiya_boy

You can use `median()` from the `statistics` module

```
import statistics

statistics.median(items)
```

You can calculate Q1 by taking the median of `median()` and `min()`, and you can calculate Q3 by taking the median of `median()` and `max()`. If you find this messy, just define a `quartile_median()` function that returns Q1,Q2,Q3

Comment: Look at the edit part of the question, thank you for your answer

Comment: that's what @dahhiya_boy proposed, but as I said in my answer, I don't think it's efficient in terms of computing time. (Correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: I'm not an expert on the subject but I'm pretty sure that's how a quartile function calculates quartiles anyways. The definition of a quartile is the median of the median and an extrema, I don't think there's a faster way to calculate it

Comment: you are perfectly right, but to calculate the median you have to sort the table, with numpy the table is sorted once, with the statistics module there are 3 function calls so the table is sorted 3 times. That's why I think it's actually going to slow down the program.

Comment: That's a good point, but considering `sort()` time is nlog2(n), it shouldn't be too much of an issue

Comment: @PierreCarceller I don't think `numpy` is slow, I have tried **500,000** randomInt values to calculate same datas (median, Q1, Q2), process always ends in **0.2s** or **0.3s**

Comment: That's not exactly my problem. I have N table of size 13 x 500 000 and for each of the tables I want to add the columns Q1, Q3 and median of so that in for each row the median column contains the median of the row. So I have to calculate N * 500,000 median values

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood you want to compute the quantiles row by row.
You can simply transpose your dataframe and then apply `pandas.DataFrame.quantile`
Not sure this is optimal thou.

```
q=data.quantile([0.25,0.50,0.75],axis=0)
```

if you have IPython active you can use the line magic: `%time` before the line to check the run time.

```
%time
q=data.quantile([0.25,0.50,0.75],axis=0)
```

This returns: `Wall time: 0 ns` to me.

Comment: Very interesting, I'll see if it saves me some computing time

Comment: Tested , it's better but not significantly

Comment: I believe a big slow down comes from transposing the dataframe. Can you check with the profiler?

Comment: I mean if you can check the computation time spent on each function and show us the results

Comment: @PierreCarceller Check the updated answer. You can actually specify on which axis you want to compute the quantiles =). This should considerably speed up the computation.

Comment: Right ! I will try it asap

Comment: It's interesting but it's still too long, I think the only solution is parallelization